# Find count of unique Ids which are not present in the given type within the same category

Tags: sql

How to find count of Unique IDs not belonging to the any other **TYPE** within that **CATEGORY**

| Category | Type | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | T1 | id1 |
| A | T1 | id2 |
| A | T1 | id5 |
| A | T2 | id3 |
| A | T2 | id1 |
| A | T3 | id1 |
| B | T4 | id1 |
| B | T4 | id2 |
| B | T5 | id3 |

I want to find count of Unique IDs not belonging to the any other type within that category

**Expected Output**

| Category | Type | Count of ID not belonging to other Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | T1 | 1 |
| A | T2 | 2 |
| A | T3 | 3 |
| B | T4 | 1 |
| B | T5 | 2 |

Explaining the output below

For **Category A**

Type T1 IDs not belonging to other type was only id1

Type T2 IDs not belonging to other type were id2 and id5

Type T3 IDs not belonging to other type were id3, id3 and id5

For **Category B**

Type T4 IDs not belonging to other type was only id3

Type T5 IDs not belonging to other type were id1 and id2

Can someone suggest a SQL query for this??

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your problem description may not be as clear as it should be. you might want to check first

Comment: @RoMEoMusTDiE Just tried to edit the description.

Comment: Based on the explaination it sounds more like you're trying to find the missing id's in a Type for the same category.

Comment: @LukStorms yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

If you left join to all possible combinations, then some will be unmatched.
Counting the unmatched will find how many are missing.

```
SELECT types.Category, types.Type
, COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ID IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS TotalMissingId
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Category, Type FROM yourtable) AS types 
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Category, ID FROM yourtable) AS ids 
  ON ids.Category = types.Category
LEFT JOIN yourtable t
  ON t.Category = types.Category
 AND t.Type = types.Type
 AND t.ID = ids.ID
GROUP BY types.Category, types.Type
ORDER BY types.Category, types.Type
```

> ```
> Category | Type | TotalMissingId
> :------- | :--- | -------------:
> A        | T1   |              1
> A        | T2   |              2
> A        | T3   |              3
> B        | T4   |              1
> B        | T5   |              2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2a394fef7d85eee82ca724c78aaee1d8)*

An alternative is to calculate the total unique id's for the categories and the types.
Then subtract them to get a total for the missing.

```
SELECT tp.Category, tp.Type
, (cat.TotalUniqueId - tp.TotalUniqueId) AS TotalMissingId
FROM (
 SELECT Category, t.Type, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS TotalUniqueId
 FROM yourtable t
 GROUP BY Category, t.Type
) AS tp
JOIN (
 SELECT Category, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS TotalUniqueId
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY Category
) AS cat ON cat.Category = tp.Category
ORDER BY tp.Category, tp.Type
```